# NodeJS (Express + PUG) MVC Port Checker

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, telnet

I am working on my local project for checking availability of applications by checking the port response status.

I've already coded the solution on my own, however it's not working as I expect so I found some code here on forum.
Let me quickly describe how I would want it to work.

- Fetch serverlist (hostname + port) from MSSQL Database. (Already works ok)
- Check application response by pinging/telnet/tcp the destination.
- Show results on website

Serverlist will contains around 200-300 destinations to check so I would like to make something that will display results of the checks asynchronously on website (currently it works the way that first application check for all results and then pass them to template) unfortunately I couldn't find solution how to update the website constantly with the results. As far I seen multiple threads it's impossible, but it's really hard to believe.

Second problem is that I'm trying to find fastest possible solution for checking the destination.
I found some code here on stack which work quite fast but I have problem with exporting the results on website. The website is being rendered before all checks are done, which ends with no results on website. And second problem is that I have problems with adding new values to array serverlist which contains results of the fetch from database, I want to add to them new key called status and that will contains results of the checks (true/false or OK/NOK)

here is the code:

```
const home = require('../controllers/home');

router.get('/',
    home.main
);


exports.main = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('home', {
        user: 'demo',
        serverlist: await exports.serverlist()
    });
};

exports.serverlist = async (req, res) => {
    var net = require('net'), Socket = net.Socket;

    var checkPort = function(port, host, callback) {
        var socket = new Socket(), status = null;

        // Socket connection established, port is open
        socket.on('connect', function() {status = 'open';socket.end();});
        socket.setTimeout(1500);// If no response, assume port is not listening
        socket.on('timeout', function() {status = 'closed';socket.destroy();});
        socket.on('error', function(exception) {status = 'closed';});
        socket.on('close', function(exception) {callback(null, status,host,port);});

        socket.connect(port, host);
    };

    let serverlist = await home.serverlist();
    console.log(serverlist);
    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        checkPort(serverlist.recordset[i].port, serverlist.recordset[i].hostname, function(error, status, host, port){
            if(status == "open"){
                console.log("Reader found: ", host, port, status);
            } else {
                console.log("Port closed: ", host, port, status);
            }
        });
    }

    console.table(serverlist.recordset);
    return serverlist;
};
```

I tried to add code here:

```
let serverlist = await home.serverlist();
        console.log(serverlist);
        for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
            checkPort(serverlist.recordset[i].port, serverlist.recordset[i].hostname, function(error, status, host, port){
                **serverlist.recordset[i].status = status;**
                if(status == "open"){
                    console.log("Reader found: ", host, port, status);
                } else {
                    console.log("Port closed: ", host, port, status);
                }
            });
        }
```

But it's not added to the results.
Thank you guys in advance for assistance with it.

Comment: Multiple threads are possible - on node side you have childproces, on website side you have WebWorker, and actually why do you need threads if you can use async code. To constantly update website you either need keep-alive header and on website make requests in interval or use sockets.

Comment: Hi Zydnar, 

Thank you so much for quick response, really appreciate that.
Checking right now for keep-alive header.

I would appreciate also assistance with adding results to array, why this might not work?

Comment: Don't forget about Connection header when using Keep-Alive see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive . What returns `console.log(serverlist);` I also can't see where you get status in this for loop.

Comment: Hi Zydnar,

here is the example return for console.log(serverlist); ->

{
  recordsets: [
    [
      [Object], [Object],
    ]
  ],
  recordset: [
    { hostname: '173.249.18.8', port: 38111 },
    { hostname: '173.249.18.8', port: 1433 }
  ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 10 ]
}

Status is coming from external module:
 var net = require('net'), Socket = net.Socket;
 socket.connect(port, host);
 socket.on('connect', function() {status = 'open';socket.end();});

As you see on the second code I added save to array:
serverlist.recordset[i].status = status;
But not work

Comment: I've read a little about socket.io, i really like the approach. Will most likely this this today! :)

Comment: Hi Guys!

i've managed to partially finish the build using socket Io.
So far works perfectly, I have just problem with 

setInterval(function() {
        io.emit('data', exports.serverlist());
    }, 5000);

Same problem as before, it doesn't wait for the results of function serverlist.
Any ideas how to make it await for the results?

Comment: If serverlist doesn't return Promise you can't await it. So if serverlist except it's async doesn't return desired value inside Promise, you have to rewrite serverlist. But no idea what happens inside controller home.serverlist - problem is there.

Comment: home.serverlist code is provided above. All what it do is:
- let serverlist = await home.serverlist(); -> Taking the hostname + port from database and save in array serverlist.
Then trough loop for checking if the port is open or not.
At the end it should save the result status into array serverlist by adding new key status (serverlist.status) => Which should obtain value true or false, or online/offline - whatever.

Comment: "home.serverlist code is provided above. All what it do is: - let serverlist = await home.serverlist();" - no it's not, you show how home.serverlist() is being used OUTSIDE home controller, not what home.serverlist function does. Problem is inside `../controllers/home`

Comment: My problem is currently only in that I can't get the variable from for loop. It always return promise no matter what I try.

exports.serverlist = async (req, res) => {
    let serverlist = await home.serverlist();

    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        serverlist.recordset[i].status = home.checkPort(serverlist.recordset[i].port, serverlist.recordset[i].hostname);
    }

    return await serverlist;
};

If I resolve this problem I am pretty good now.
Calling function by: console.log(await exports.serverlist());

Comment: The problem in above is that the function should wait for arrays in serverlist.recordset[*].status to be finished but I have no clue how I can make return to check all iteration inside recordset[].

Comment: Finally resolved!!! I think it's not the proper way but for me is SATISFYING enough. Maybe someone can correct it to make it better :D

With old method excution time to get the results was 5.181s !
With new method execution time to get the results is  1.015s !

Which is really really good timing.
New corrected code: (Unfortunately I cannot answer such long message so let me split it)

Comment: exports.serverlist = async (req, res) => {
    let serverlist = await home.serverlist();
    let promises = [];
    console.time("LOOP WITH AWAIT INSIDE STARTED");
    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        promises.push(home.checkPort(serverlist.recordset[i].port, serverlist.recordset[i].hostname));
    }

    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        serverlist.recordset[i].status = await promises[i];
    }

    console.timeEnd("LOOP WITH AWAIT INSIDE ENDED");
    return serverlist;
};

This code resolved my problem

Comment: It run the loop in async and don't wait for response, so all tcp checks can run in background and end with positive result or timeout (imagine, if timeout would be 5 seconds I would need to wait 5sec * length of array) now I wait second for array to trigger all tcp check and then just wait maximum 5 seconds to make timeout end and get all results.

Do you think guys this solution is good enough?

Comment: Looking at rules you actually should post answer to own question instead put it as comment. I'm glad you managed to solve the problem. However keep in mind some services may seem to be offline while actually it's just terrible ping (consider adding setting for max response time).

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkPort = async (port, host, timeout = 1000) => {
    return await isPortReachable(port, {timeout: timeout, host: host});
};
```

```html
exports.serverlist = async (req, res) => {
    let serverlist = await home.serverlist();
    let promises = [];

    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        promises.push(home.checkPort(serverlist.recordset[i].port, serverlist.recordset[i].hostname, 1000));
    }

    for(let i=0; i < serverlist.recordset.length; i++){
        serverlist.recordset[i].status = await promises[i];
    }

    return await serverlist;
};
```

Above code resolved my problem, if someone know better quality way that would be glad to hear :-) Anyway at this moment the function doesn't wait for response inside the loop, so it run all checks async.